# Loading subview above view's Layer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I followed a tutorial on taking pictures using AvFoundation Framework..
so i am not proficient in it.. thats one point.

In the app..in the nib.
There is a view(SUBVIEW) as a sub view of the main view(MAINVIEW).
And there is a an image view and button as a subview of the subview View(SUBVIEW) not the Main view.

There is code in the tutorial (for the subview)

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];


    [self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
```

but after  applying this the image view appears in back of the SUBVIEW not in front of it as it was supposed to in the nib..
So how to get image view appear in front of the view..vimagepreview is the SUBVIEW

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but: If you're looking at the order of views in the nib editor in Xcode, the topmost view listed is actually the furthest back.  So put whatever view you want to be in front of everything else on the BOTTOM of the list of views in Xcode nib editor.

Comment: i did it correct. imageviw is added as a subview to The SUBVIEW in the nib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new view programmatically, add the layer, and then add the view to the subview.

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:SUBVIEW.bounds];
[newView.layer addSublayer: captureVideoPreviewLayer];
[SUBVIEW addSubview: newView];
```

That should make sure the layer is above the subview.

Comment: If you have any touch button on this newView! it will not work! will not work on iOS7

Answer (score 2):

I guess you require to bring your subview (image view container view) in front.

Check this out: [bringSubViewToFront:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:)

Its `UIView` class method.

Let me know whether this works for you or not

Comment: i tried bringing subview to front but still the image view is in back.

Answer (score 1):

This will work on both iOS7 and iOS8.

```
[videoPreviewLayerParentView.layer insertSublayer:videoPreviewLayer atIndex:0];
[videoPreviewLayerParentView.layer insertSublayer:aboveView.layer atIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering the z-index:

```
//subview to go infront
frontView.layer.zPosition = 100

//layer to go to back
backLayer.zPosition = 0
```